# Engine running rough after spirited driving

Tags: engine, noise, rough-idle

My car is a 2003 Chevy Impala 3.4L, with just over 200,000mi on it.

I've checked the oil, it hadn't been on the road in about a month. My wife and I had a race a few days ago with her in the Impala and I was in my Golf. She was driving it hard and this morning when I started the Impala I hear a very loud ticking sound, and the engine shakes.  It bogs out when I give it gas and runs terrible.

What can I check or what could we have damaged?

Comment: Hello @Brady. Welcome to the site. Please try and use proper punctuation and grammar in your question to make it easy to read and understand.  Poorly formatted questions don't get a lot of attention.  I've made some edits to help get some more views.

Comment: We need some direction here. Could you hook it up to a scan tool and log some data? Without it we would be flying blind

Comment: See [Why am I being asked to connect a scan tool to my vehicle? Why am I being asked for Diagnostic Trouble Codes?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675)

Comment: Brady, I gotta ask.   What is your expected life of this car (i.e. mileage before needing an complete engine rebuild?)  hint: does the oil light come on and stay on for a sorta long time when your first start the car up at idle?

Comment: Too many possible answers, hard to diagnose a 200K motor here.

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of support from OP - question remains too broad.